# Change hardcoded default front page - Drupal 8

Tags: drupal

I need to change the hardcoded part of the default front page shown in below screenshot

[image]

This may be easy, but, the part `http://www.website.com` is hardcoded, how it can be changed?

FW: Drupal 8 
OS: Centos 7
WS: Apache 
DB: Mysql

Comment: This doesn't work like that, the part before the first slash is the domain/host name. hosts should be registered in `/etc/hosts` and should be handled by your web server, then in drupal you can change the `$base_url` accordingly in `settings.php`. If you still need help I suggest you ask another question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer will be: you don't have to change that part.

It's not hard-coded. Drupal can detect current domain so if you move site to different domain this part will also change to correct one. Good thing with Drupal is that it keeps paths in relative formats so when you move site to new domain they will work out of box (unlike i.e. WordPress). Just make sure that urls you enter manually (i.e. links which are part of some wysiwyg edited content) are also in root relative format.

Answer (score 0):

As per @Milang Accepted Answer, Here I found a practical example Drupal default front page URL is not hardcoded.

You can find the [example here](https://onexlab-io.medium.com/change-drupal-default-front-page-base-url-b5fbc4efcae4)